# Running several sequences of Tasks serially using TPL

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a class that returns an IEnumerable. I then execute these tasks in order. Let's say the class is TaskProvider.

```
public class TaskProvider {
  public IEnumerable<Task> SomeThingsToDo() { return work; }
}
```

I am executing these with the following:

```
public void ExecuteTasks(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    var enumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator();
    ExecuteNextTask(enumerator);
}

static void ExecuteNextTask(IEnumerator<Task> enumerator)
{
    bool moveNextSucceeded = enumerator.MoveNext();

    if (!moveNextSucceeded) return;

    enumerator
        .Current
        .ContinueWith(x => ExecuteNextTask(enumerator));
}
```

Now I have a situation where I might have multiple instances of TaskProvider, each generating a list of tasks. I want each list of tasks to be executed in order, meaning that all the tasks from one provider finish before the next one starts.

Then, most importantly, I need to know when all the tasks are completed.

What's the TPL way of accomplishing this?

(FWIW, I'm using the Async CTP for Silverlight.)

Comment: I also wonder if I am reinventing the wheel with my ExecuteTask logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the approach I took, and so far all my tests are passing.

First, I created a unioned enumerable of all the tasks from the various providers:

```
var tasks = from provider in providers
            from task in provider.SomeThingsToDo()
            select task;
```

I believe that part of my original problem was that I did a ToList (more or less) and thus began the execution of the tasks prematurely.

Next, I added a callback to ExecuteTasks and ExecuteNextTask. Admittedly, not as clean as I'd hoped. Here's the revised implementation:

```
public void ExecuteTasks(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, Action callback)
{
    var enumerator = tasks.GetEnumerator();
    ExecuteNextTask(enumerator, callback);
}

static void ExecuteNextTask(IEnumerator<Task> enumerator, Action callback)
{
    bool moveNextSucceeded = enumerator.MoveNext();

    if (!moveNextSucceeded)
    {
        if (callback != null) callback();
        return;
    }

    enumerator
        .Current
        .ContinueWith(x => ExecuteNextTask(enumerator, callback));
}
```

I didn't need a thread-safe structure for storing the list of tasks, because the list is generated only once.

Answer (score 0):

at worst you could have a static concurrentqueue of Ienumerables which you ExecuteNextTask method works it's way through...

something like:

```
public static class ExecuteController {

    private static ConcurrentQueue<IEnumerable<Task>> TaskLists = new ConcurrentQueue<IEnumerable<Task>>();

    public void ExecuteTaskList(IEnumerable<Task> tasks) {
          TaskLists.Enqueue(tasks);
          TryStartExec();
    }         

    public void TryStartExec() {
         check if there is a new task list and if so exec it with your code. 
         possibly need to lock around the dequeue but i think there is an atomic dequeue method on concurrent queue..
    }

}
```

Comment: ConcurrentQueue<T> doesn't exist in Silverlight (or in the new async ctp libs). Though I'm experimenting now with a similar approach based on your answer.